# pyproj, proj4 doesn't return same coordinates after inverse conversion

Tags: python, proj, utm

I'm trying to interpolate between coordinates, as a step in that process I convert latlong to UTM so I can work in metric.

I don't get the expected latlong when converting back, reproduced below:

```
>>> import pyproj
>>> pyproj.__version__
'1.9.2'
>>> p = pyproj.Proj("+proj=utm +zone=33 +north +ellps=WGS84 +datum=WGS84 +units=m +no_defs")
>>> p(58.4, 15.6)
(5579373.890337878, 2328887.997220567)
>>> p(*p(58.4, 15.6), inverse=True) # Should return (58.4, 15.6)
(58.284316956873305, 15.63501250163002)
```

Is there a good explanation for this? How do I do what I want without this issue?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Your input coordinates are in the wrong order. Pyproj expects long, lat.

```
>>> import pyproj
>>> p = pyproj.Proj(init='epsg:32633')
>>> p(*p(15.6, 58.4), inverse=True)
(15.6, 58.399999999999991)
```

Comment: Subtle, thought it could be because projection/rounding errors, couldn't figure out how though. Thanks a lot!

Comment: Many transforms are only reversible within a restricted area. Check out the red strip in the map at http://spatialreference.org/ref/epsg/32633/. Outside your UTM zone, the algorithm's robustness decreases.